# Can I access SessionState from within an NUnit test?

Tags: session, nunit, session-state

One of my methods in an NUnit test checks a Session-State variable :

if (Sesssion[variableName] == null) ...

and the NUnit test is failing with err:

> System.Web.HttpException: Session
>   state can only be used when
>   enableSessionState is set to true,
>   either in a configuration file or in
>   the Page directive. Please also make
>   sure that
>   System.Web.SessionStateModule or a
>   custom session state module is
>   included in the
>   \\
>   section in the application
>   configuration.

I tried taking the test method out of a class library and putting it into the codebehind cs of an aspx page that set EnableSessionState="True" in the aspx page directive.  Added a web config with  sessionState mode = "InProc" in the web config, then tried < pages enableSessionState ="true"/> in the web.config.

Nunit tests still failed on the session state action.

Do I have to mock these out?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can access Session from your unit tests without mocking it.

Have a look at Phil Haack's HttpSimulator
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/19/unit-tests-web-code-without-a-web-server-using-httpsimulator.aspx